Statistics for protein intensity change across timepoints with several replicates in R
I have a list of protein intensities across 3 timepoints for 5 replicates.
I want to evaluate whether the change in protein intensities across timepoints is statistically different between replicates.
Data frame code
dataframe <- structure(list(genes = c("ZFTA", "IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", 
"IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", "IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", 
"IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", "IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", 
"IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", "IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", 
"IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", "IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", 
"IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", "IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", 
"IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", "IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", 
"IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1", "ZFTA", "IPO5", "COPE", "APOL1"), replicate = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), levels = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), intensity = c(0, 5.3, 
0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 6.4, 5.2, 234.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10.9, 
6, 121, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6.9, 11.4, 125, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), timepoint = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("2", "24", "48"), class = "factor"), 
    mean = c(2534.11613603473, 2534.11613603473, 2534.11613603473, 
    2534.11613603473, 2545.86975397974, 2545.86975397974, 2545.86975397974, 
    2545.86975397974, 1041.9492040521, 1041.9492040521, 1041.9492040521, 
    1041.9492040521, 2352.51975397974, 2352.51975397974, 2352.51975397974, 
    2352.51975397974, 1549.3483357453, 1549.3483357453, 1549.3483357453, 
    1549.3483357453, 732.627062228654, 732.627062228654, 732.627062228654, 
    732.627062228654, 3142.20426917511, 3142.20426917511, 3142.20426917511, 
    3142.20426917511, 1043.8981910275, 1043.8981910275, 1043.8981910275, 
    1043.8981910275, 425.870405209841, 425.870405209841, 425.870405209841, 
    425.870405209841, 3623.80745296671, 3623.80745296671, 3623.80745296671, 
    3623.80745296671, 540.550434153401, 540.550434153401, 540.550434153401, 
    540.550434153401, 270.068668596237, 270.068668596237, 270.068668596237, 
    270.068668596237, 3062.0981910275, 3062.0981910275, 3062.0981910275, 
    3062.0981910275, 1628.59247467438, 1628.59247467438, 1628.59247467438, 
    1628.59247467438, 528.705282199711, 528.705282199711, 528.705282199711, 
    528.705282199711), sd = c(25094.6719445552, 25094.6719445552, 
    25094.6719445552, 25094.6719445552, 21058.9289049973, 21058.9289049973, 
    21058.9289049973, 21058.9289049973, 9975.3033998113, 9975.3033998113, 
    9975.3033998113, 9975.3033998113, 26179.750502137, 26179.750502137, 
    26179.750502137, 26179.750502137, 10207.7081411541, 10207.7081411541, 
    10207.7081411541, 10207.7081411541, 6420.40357806305, 6420.40357806305, 
    6420.40357806305, 6420.40357806305, 39498.0097492931, 39498.0097492931, 
    39498.0097492931, 39498.0097492931, 7936.15443848429, 7936.15443848429, 
    7936.15443848429, 7936.15443848429, 3413.66443657427, 3413.66443657427, 
    3413.66443657427, 3413.66443657427, 45997.397176612, 45997.397176612, 
    45997.397176612, 45997.397176612, 4168.32150996512, 4168.32150996512, 
    4168.32150996512, 4168.32150996512, 2961.16684541202, 2961.16684541202, 
    2961.16684541202, 2961.16684541202, 33839.982382166, 33839.982382166, 
    33839.982382166, 33839.982382166, 11360.6060492469, 11360.6060492469, 
    11360.6060492469, 11360.6060492469, 4131.58489947706, 4131.58489947706, 
    4131.58489947706, 4131.58489947706), id = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    1383L, 1384L, 1385L, 1386L, 2765L, 2766L, 2767L, 2768L, 4147L, 
    4148L, 4149L, 4150L, 5529L, 5530L, 5531L, 5532L, 6911L, 6912L, 
    6913L, 6914L, 8293L, 8294L, 8295L, 8296L, 9675L, 9676L, 9677L, 
    9678L, 11057L, 11058L, 11059L, 11060L, 12439L, 12440L, 12441L, 
    12442L, 13821L, 13822L, 13823L, 13824L, 15203L, 15204L, 15205L, 
    15206L, 16585L, 16586L, 16587L, 16588L, 17967L, 17968L, 17969L, 
    17970L, 19349L, 19350L, 19351L, 19352L)), row.names = c("1.2.1", 
"1.2.2", "1.2.3", "1.2.4", "1.24.6911", "1.24.6912", "1.24.6913", 
"1.24.6914", "1.48.13821", "1.48.13822", "1.48.13823", "1.48.13824", 
"2.2.1383", "2.2.1384", "2.2.1385", "2.2.1386", "2.24.8293", 
"2.24.8294", "2.24.8295", "2.24.8296", "2.48.15203", "2.48.15204", 
"2.48.15205", "2.48.15206", "3.2.2765", "3.2.2766", "3.2.2767", 
"3.2.2768", "3.24.9675", "3.24.9676", "3.24.9677", "3.24.9678", 
"3.48.16585", "3.48.16586", "3.48.16587", "3.48.16588", "4.2.4147", 
"4.2.4148", "4.2.4149", "4.2.4150", "4.24.11057", "4.24.11058", 
"4.24.11059", "4.24.11060", "4.48.17967", "4.48.17968", "4.48.17969", 
"4.48.17970", "5.2.5529", "5.2.5530", "5.2.5531", "5.2.5532", 
"5.24.12439", "5.24.12440", "5.24.12441", "5.24.12442", "5.48.19349", 
"5.48.19350", "5.48.19351", "5.48.19352"), class = "data.frame")


I tried this:
library(rstatix)
res.aov <- anova_test(data = dataframe, dv = intensity, wid = replicate, within = timepoint, between = replicate)
get_anova_table(res.aov)


Resulting in this:

Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: data = map(.data$data, dplyr::distinct, replicate, .keep_all = TRUE).
ℹ In group 1: replicate = 1.
Caused by error in map():
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in .f():
! Must use existing variables.
✖ replicate not found in .data.

I think maybe I am approaching this entirely wrong. Please help
TIA

Can you please make your example more reproducible? Can you provide some data for us, so that if we run it, we can get the same error as you do? Also, what package do anova_test() and get_anova_table() come from?

@qdread Have updated with code for data. Stats test come from rstatix

I am a little confused what you are testing. I see you have a column genes but it is not included in the anova syntax. You want to compare whether the replicates have different mean intensities, accounting for the fact that each replicate was measured at different timepoints, but ignoring which of the genes it is?

@qdread Essentially I want to know whether the change in proteomic profile over time is similar or statistically different between replicates. For this, I guess it would add more power to consider each gene its own dependent variable but this seems very complicated?

Based on your description of the data, it sounds like you have repeated measures within subjects. The subjects are the unique combinations of genes and replicate. We need to create an additional column identifying those unique combinations and then pass that column name to the wid argument of anova_test().
Before providing the code, though, I will strongly caution you that this is very unlikely to yield useful predictions because your intensity variable is not even close to normally distributed. It is mostly zeros with a handful of positive values. I would recommend looking into alternatives such as generalized linear mixed models (zero-inflated), nonparametric tests, or to turn the intensity variable into a binary variable (zero vs. nonzero) and fit a binomial model. But the following code will do the ANOVA as you requested.
dataframe$gene_rep <- with(dataframe, interaction(genes, replicate))
res.aov <- anova_test(data = dataframe, dv = intensity, wid = gene_rep, within = timepoint, between = replicate)
get_anova_table(res.aov)


Thanks for your patience and the help! I'll look into GLM, do you think EdgeR would be appropriate?
